# How different does each output unit have to be?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I'll use the example of classifying pumpkins. Take the example of the Cinderella pumpkin

[image]

Versus the gourd pumpkin

[image]

Intuitively, it may seem wise to classify these images as two different outputs, `cinderella-pumpkin` and `gourd-pumpkin`, due to how different they look.

My question is, if I take a training set of images that includes both cinderella pumpkins and gourd pumpkins and classify both of them under the category of `pumpkin`, will the performance of the network be worse than if I instead separated them into two categories? What is about the threshold for when two objects are so different that they should be put into separate categories?

Or to take a more extreme example for the sake of clarity, if I took pictures of cats and pictures of pineapples and classified them under the same category, how would the ability of the network be affected in classifying each respective object in comparison to if one created a `cat` output and a `pineapple` output?

Comment: Sorry, I realize this question may better belong in Cross Validated

Comment: Actually, I think this question belongs back on your own desk.  You speak of performance and accuracy, but you haven't yet determined the purpose of the network.  Thresholds and outcomes depend on the classifications you design into the training data.  What do you expect this network to accomplish when you're done?  If you want it to discriminate edible and inedible objects, or orange from green, or animals from plants, then your pumpkin discrimination is not functional.

Comment: @prune you're missing the point of my question. Im asking whether or not having two types of objects (in this case cinderella and gourd pumpkins) under the same category of pumpkin affects the ability of the network to identify each respective object. In this case the sole purpose of the network is to identify pumpkin vs not a pumpkin.

Comment: I believe I understand now.  You have two designs in mind,  One puts all pumpkin photos into one large category.  The model's task for the prediction set is to discriminate pumpkin from anything else.  The other design divides the pumpkins by "sufficiently different" varieties.  The prediction task is "does this photo fall into any *one* of my **N** pumpkin categories?"

Comment: Your follow-up question is, "when is it worth splitting into those **N** distinct classifications?"

Comment: yes, and whether or not one performs better than the other, and preferably some explanation into why that is so.

Comment: yeah thats the follow up question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the inherent similarity of your training observations.  I don't set up a threshold: I use power iteration clustering (or other unsupervised classification) to guide me on where there are significant divisions in the training data.  k-means is also a popular choice, since it's a common implementation, and relatively easy to comprehend.

The other consideration is the similarity of "non-pumpkin" data, such as a basketball (compared to your Cinderella).  Again, I take the unsupervised learning approach.  In this case, I expect that a basketball would plot closer to the Cinderella than either would to the gourd.  This suggests separate classes for pumpkin types -- or perhaps more feature detection in the image processing, to find the similarities across pumpkin varieties.

Does that help?